# Multithreading the Merge Sort

Tags: java, multithreading, mergesort, executors

I am trying to create a multithreaded version of the Merge Sort and I am using executors for that (pls let me know if there is any other better way). I want the two threads to run simultaneously. I am new to Executors and finding it difficult to code even after seeing some tutorials. Any method of parallelizing other than executors is of course most welcomed.

```
public static void ASC(int[] input_array, int left, int right, int[] temp_array) // Sorts in ascending order
{
    if(left < right)
    {
        int middle = ( left + right )>>>1 ; // Same as (left + right)/2, but avoids overflow for large left and right and is probably faster

    // I want to run these 2 codes in 2 threads simultaneously
        ASC(input_array, left, middle, temp_array);
        ASC(input_array, middle+1, right, temp_array);

    // And I want the execution to stop here until the threads are finished
    // I know invokeAll() will do the job but I cant seem to code it properly
    // Pls tell me how to do it properly along with what classes to import as Im new to Executors.
    // Any other method of parallelizing is most welcomed

    // The part below is the Merge Procedure
        int j = middle + 1;
        int temp_indx = left;
        int left2 = left;
        while((left <= middle) && (j <= right))
        {
            if (input_array[left] < input_array[j])
            {
                temp_array[temp_indx] = input_array[left];
                left = left + 1;
            }
            else
            {
                temp_array[temp_indx] = input_array[j];
                j = j + 1;
            }
            temp_indx = temp_indx + 1;
        }
        while(left <= middle)
        {
            temp_array[temp_indx] = input_array[left];
            left = left + 1;
            temp_indx = temp_indx + 1;
        }
        while(j <= right)
        {
            temp_array[temp_indx] = input_array[j];
            j = j + 1;
            temp_indx = temp_indx + 1;
        }
        while(right >= left2)
        {
            input_array[right] = temp_array[right];
            right = right - 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: To avoid overflow for middle, use middle = left + (right-left)>>1; . If interested, I made a [windows example of multi-threaded merge sort](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/148025/multithreaded-bottom-up-merge-sort). It's windows specific and not generic.

Comment: @rcgldr, thats a great idea, what about parallelizing the Dual Pivot QuickSort, I think it could be faster than the parallelized Merge Sort. Regarding the overflow, pls have a look here https://research.googleblog.com/2006/06/extra-extra-read-all-about-it-nearly.html

Comment: googleblog's comment about overflow would applies to top down merge sort. My example and most real world implementations of merge sort are bottom up, where there is no calculated middle, so no overflow issue. For the overflow issue to occur on a 32 bit machine, with signed integers, there would have to be more than 2 billion elements, with unsigned integers, more than 4 billion elements, not likely to happen.

Comment: For parallel quick sort, each thread operates on it's own part of the array, then the sorted sub-arrays are merged after the threads complete their sort. For sorting arrays of integers, radix sort would be quickest. On a system with 16 registers (like X86 in 64 bit mode), it's close between a 4 way merge sort (not shown in my example) and quick sort. If sorting an array of pointers to objects, merge sort is faster. If sorting the objects directly, then quick sort can be faster. The point of my example was to show that the small loops in the merge logic were cpu bound, not memory bound.

Comment: googleblog's issue about overflow would apply to bottom up merge sort, but for a different calculation. Typically the number of elements in each run is doubled until the number of elements per run >= number of elements in an array. So on a 32 bit machine, if doubling the number of elements calculation produces a result >= 2 billion (or 4 billion), overflow could occur, but generally there's not enough memory on a 32 bit machine to contain two array large enough for this to be an issue. It's a non-issue on a 64 bit machine (assuming 64 bit math).